# Returning Specific, Non-Repeating Values

Tags: excel-formula

First time posting, though I have lurked around for quite some time.

I am trying to match specific information from a power query created table to another table. The data I am trying to pull can potentially repeat, so it needed to be a formula that would remove that. The current formula I am using is:

```
{=(OFFSET(Sales!$A$1:$A$100000,SMALL(IF(CONCATENATE($B$48,$O$3)=Sales!$A:$A,ROW(Sales!$A$1:$A$100000)-ROW(INDEX(Sales!$A$1:$A$100000,1,1))),ROW()-48),COLUMN()+2))}
```

and it was originally working for my test data. Once I pulled the data from the database using power query, however, I continue to get #value errors. The formula looks up a concatenated value on the power query worksheet compared to one created on the current worksheet.

Any advice would be appreciated.